# $f(X)＝X^p＋mp^2(X-1)(X-2) \cdots( X-p＋2)-p$ has exactly two non-real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

How to prove $f（X）＝X^p＋mp^2（X-1）（X-2）...（X-p＋2）-p$ has just 2 non-real roots when $m$ is large enough?
I couldn't find even one solution of this polynomial.
But writing graphs with computer,the titled statement seems to be true.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial has exactly two **non-real** roots for $m$ big enough.

Indeed, using the sign rule of Descartes, we see that, because $f$ has exactly $p-2$ sign changes of the coefficients, $f$ has at most  $p-2$ *positive* real roots. Since $f(-X)$ has only negative coefficients for $m\ge 0$, there is no negative real root.
Hence $f$ has at most $p-2$ real roots. However, for $m$ big enough
it is clear that $f$ has positive roots nearby $1,2\ldots ,p-2$. So we are done. The polynomial has exactly two *non-real* roots, so that its Galois group is isomorphic to $S_p$.

Again, here is the polynomial:
$$
f(X)=X^p+mp^2(X-1)(X-2)\cdots (X-p+2)-p
$$

Comment: Thank you, but why f（X）has at least n-2 roots when m is big? how I can formally prove that?

Comment: Formally with estimates, so that the roots are close enough to the $p-2$ values $1,2,\ldots ,p-2$. There exists an explicit bound on how big $m$ needs to be - try it!

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. Consider $p=3$. Then for general $m$ the polynomial has eiher one or three **real** roots. It **never** has two real roots (if the multiplicity of the roots is taken into account).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I made this initially as a comment but the question was not corrected. Even now it has false title.